# What is macro SINIX stand for?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, cl

I am analyzing the code of a project. 
There is some code gets compiled when SINIX is defined.

```
#ifdef SINIX 
    do something()
#else
    do dosomethingelse() 
#endif
```

Can anyone tell me if SINIX is OS specific define statement or it is a project specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a project specific definition. My guess would be support for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SINIX .

Grepping through the GCC sources, SINIX support was removed from GCC in 2003. Based on some ChangeLog entries, it seems GCC, back when it did support SINIX, set the predefined macros "SNI" and "sinix", but not "SINIX".